# R code: Dynamic Variables in a loop

Tags: r, bash

I'm facing a challenge in `R`. I'm writing a code that incorporates another code written in `C++` called `MHX`.

MHX is used for chemical data analysis by inputting some concentrations, etc. The integration between `R` and `MHX` works fine. So I'm able to write my `MHX` code definitions in the form of `cat`(*CODE HERE*) then calling a `bash` command to run `MHX` from terminal.

Now the results from `MHX` are given as tab delimited data tables that I am able to read without a problem in `R`. The problem is that I use `R` to simulate a large number of `MHX` calculations using loops.

Hence the need to write `dynamic variables` and here were I'm stuck. Let me give you more information with examples of my `R` code:

```
for (i in 1:100) {

fin  <-  file.create("input/ex1")  #MHX input file
fout <- file.create("output/ex1.out") #MHX output file

FNM <-  paste0("table_data/pH", i, ".txt")  #filename used inside MHX definition
file.create(FNM)   #this is used to create FNM table in R
fXY <-  file.create(paste0("table_data/ECOMXY", i, ".txt"))  

ifelse (HERE SOME MATHEMATICAL DEFINITIONS OF SOME VARIABLES)

ksource(MHXCode)  #THIS CALLS MY MHX CODE which is inside another R code called `MHXCode` using a custom function KSOURCE. No problem here.
```

Up to here I don't have major problems. Now I need to setup the `dynamic variables`:
First I am creating variables `PHL1` to `PHL100`

```
assign(paste("PHL", i, sep=""), read.table(paste0("table_data/pH", i, ".txt") ,skip=0, sep="\t", head=TRUE, na.strings = "-Inf"))
```

Each `PHL` table contains two rows and about 20 columns. Now I am interested in creating data `frames` from the second row for each column. Take for example row number 1 which is called `EMF`, ideally I need to do the following for all tables from `PHL`to `PHL100` which is very tedious:

```
EMFT <- cbind(PHL1$EMF[2], PHL2$EMF[2], PHL3$EMF[2], PHL4$EMF[2], PHL5$EMF[2], PHL6$EMF[2],PHL7$EMF[2], PHL8$EMF[2], PHL9$EMF[2], PHL10$EMF[2], ....... etc up to PHL100! )
```

I tried many things to achieve the above, but I was not successful, including:

```
XX <- assign(paste0("PHL", i, "$EMF[2]"), cat(paste0("PHL", i, "$EMF[2]")))
```

I will need to do the same for other variables in order to be able to create some complicated plots. I hope anyone would be able to help.

I must mention that the main problem with assign is that I get qouted names of variables hence cannot return their values. Also for cat, you cannot use it to return a value, you will get `NULL` in the example above. Simple I am stuck!!

Please help.

Comment: use a list... `lapply(list.files(pattern='PLH.*'), read_csv)` to read them in.  Then you can mash them together using `cbind` and `do.call`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. This does not really work well for me. However, it gave me some clues to answer my question (see below)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Justin he gave me a clue to answer my question. Here is what I have done:

```
files <- list.files(path="table_data", pattern=".dat", full.names=T); files
FRM <- NULL
for (f in files){
dat <- read.table(f, skip=0, header=TRUE, sep="\t", na.strings="",quote="", colClasses="character")[2,]
```

## note that the [2, ] argument means that you skip all lines except line number 2 while keeping header which exactly what I was looking for.

Now I can bind it all in one table for my plots.

```
FRM <- rbind(FRM, dat)
```

This is a short answer and I think it is neat, sorted!

Comment: instead of using `[2,]` you can use the `nrow` argument to `read.table` and save your computer the work of reading in all that extra data.